# Google protobuf memory leak when used with valgrind

Tags: c++11, memory-leaks, protocol-buffers, valgrind

Using google protobuf version 3.5.1
Has anyone come across this kind of leak with **Messagelite**

```
==4096== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 397 of 2,856
==4096==    at 0x4C3217F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4096==    by 0x52AB2C4: Create<google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArenaBase<google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet, google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArena>::Container> (arena.h:361)
==4096==    by 0x52AB2C4: google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArenaBase<google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet, google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArena>::mutable_unknown_fields_slow() (metadata_lite.h:153)
==4096==    by 0x6504716: google::protobuf::internal::ReflectionOps::Clear(google::protobuf::Message*) (reflection_ops.cc:139)
==4096==    by 0x6475627: InlineParseFromCodedStream (message_lite.cc:129)
==4096==    by 0x6475627: InlineParseFromArray (message_lite.cc:142)
==4096==    by 0x6475627: google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (message_lite.cc:207)
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50414346/how-to-free-protocol-buffer-memory